# What's the meaning of "[]", "<>", "{}" in SYNOPSIS of a command?

Tags: manpage

Here are some examples:

from `man` page of a command:

```
$ man man
man [-acdfFhkKtwW] [--path] [-m system] [-p string] [-C config_file] [-M pathlist] [-P pager] [-S section_list] [section] name ...
...
```

from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g:

```
:[range]g/<pattern>/cmd
```

from http://bullium.com/support/vim.html:

```
:wq {file}
```

1. What's the meaning of `[...]`, `<...>`, `{...}`, and those things without any surroundings?
2. Is there a standardized definition of the usage of symbols?

Comment: There is this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771080.aspx but it might be Microsoft specific

Comment: In general it is very context specific. Usually [] means optional, while <> and {} are describing what they should be replaced with

Answer (score 3):

The examples you gave vary because the vim commands are to be used within Vim itself, not on the shell command line.

`[]` is usually reserved for optional arguments on shell commands.

`<>` in your example is used for required arguments to a vim commmand.
`{}` in your example is used for an optional argument on a vim command.

The later two seem to be VIM specific, but `[]` is pretty standard notation for signifying optional arguments.

Comment: What about `()`? As shown in [git-reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)'s SYNOPSIS.